# Javascript add more button runtime

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to add dynamic textboxes using Javascript.

When someone clicks on the `Add More` Link than 2 text boxes will be added dynamically.

I have the HTML code which I want to repeat when someone clicks on `Add More` link.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">Employer</div>
    <div class="right"><input type="text" class="tripObject" name="employer" id="employer" value=""> &nbsp; <strong>Position</strong> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="tripObject" name="position" id="position" value=""> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:addFormField();">Add More</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And the `JavaScript` code is:

```
window.optionId =1;

window.addFormField = function() {
    optionId += 1;
    var thisOption = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'row ' + optionId
    }).append(
        $('<div>').attr({
            'class': 'left'
        }).html('Employer'), 
        /*$('<div>').attr({
            'class': 'right'}),*/
        $('<input>').attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'size': 20,
            'name': 'option_' + optionId,
            'class': 'tripObject',
            'validate': 'required:true'
        }), 
        $('<a>').attr({
            'href': '#'
        }).html('Remove').click(function() {
            thisOption.remove();
        })
    ).appendTo('#editeducationInfo');
};
```

Comment: seems you didn't ask anything in your question :)

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you making it complex? As you are using `jquery` in your code, here is the easy way of appending the existing elements by `clone` and `append` method.

**Doc:** [$.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [$.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var obj =  $("div.right").eq(0).clone(); //this will clone the html elements
$("div.row").append(obj); //this will append to the existing elements
```

**Update:**

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JV8eU/)

Comment: how can i change the name attribute of textbox?

Comment: @PrinceBijvani why do you need to change the `name` ?

Comment: one more thing when someone click on Add more then only add that boxes and when someone click on remove then the box will remove..any idea?

Comment: `Mukul Kapoor` is correct, you need to change the `id` as that must be unique but `name` doesn't matter

Comment: @PrinceBijvani, Check my updated answer, i provided the fiddle link for the remove functionality

Comment: it's amazing, thank you very much. but one more thing when i click on remove the original 2 textboxes also removed. have any idea to remains that 2 textboxes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23638/discussion-between-don-and-prince-bijvani)

Answer (score 0):

DON's answer is correct. But along with that, you also need to change the ID and NAME attribute. Otherwise retrieving data from form submission will create a problem if all elements will have same name.

Comment: No need to change the `name`, changing `id` alone better